# Radar lobes vs forever propagating waves

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, antennas, radar

I'm trying to learn some more about radar and I'm confused about "lobes". My understanding of EM radiation is that it radiates forever or until something physical blocks it, but directional antennas seem to be manipulating the waves through construction and deconstruction which results in these lobes with a finite end point.

What exactly has happened at the end part of the [main lobe here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_lobe) that causes it to round off nicely like that? Is this the same wave destructive interference that causes this lobing to begin with? Beyond the tip of the main lobe is there no more energy propagating?

Answer (score 3):

The diagrams you are looking at do not show how *far* the radiation propagates, it shows the *power* of the radiation in different directions.

The portions far from the center have the highest power.  If you have a receiver in one of the very weak directions, it doesn't mean that radiation cannot reach you.  Just that the total power reaching you will be low, perhaps below the threshold of utility unless you are very close to the antenna.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. So basically it's showing the extent to which the radar concentrates all its energy into a single beam. Does that explain why the tip of the main lobe is marked as zero dB and all other points measured relative to this? I also read that to measure the width in degrees of the main lobe you find the point either side of the boresight line where power has dropped by half, or -3dB. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unknown lobes may end in unwanted radiation in unwanted directions. Em radiation can push through any blockage over time .